# Bad behavior of activities overview when workspaces span displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.04, workspaces, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 and noticed a bad behavior of gnome's activities overview:

I have two monitors and work with the option "Workspaces span displays" enabled. In the gnome configuration of ubuntu, however, when I open the activities overview I see **all** opened windows in every workspace in the secondary display.

Let's say I have firefox open on the secondary display in workspace 1. If I open activities overview in workspace 3 I see this firefox window, although I've nothing open in WS 3.

I've been using ubuntu gnome since its first release and never had such problem.

Is there an additional option to toggle, or shall I submit a bug report?

---

EDIT: A bug report actually exists [on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1743736)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written as an edit in the question, a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1743736) actually exists on launchpad.

A bug fix currently does not exist. As a workaround, however, you can use [this gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/).